# How to find an isomorphism between two projecive subvarieties?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, projective-space, projective-varieties

Consider the projective $2$-space $\mathbb{P}^2$ over the field $\mathbb Q$ given by the homogeneous cordinates $[X:Y:Z]$. Cinsider the following two elliptic curves in homogeneous coordinates: $$E_1: (X^3+Y^3=Z^3)~~\text{and}~~E_2:=(Y^2Z=X^3-432Z^3).$$
We can think of the solution sets of $E_1,E_2$ in $\mathbb{P}^2$ as projective subvarieties $V(E_1)$ and $V(E_2)$ respectively.

Then the rational map $\varphi:=[12Z, 36(X-Y),X+Y]$ is a morphism from $V(E_1) \to V(E_2)$, since $\varphi$ is defined at every point of $\mathbb P^2(\mathbb Q)$.

> How to show $\varphi$ is an isomorphism ?

---

We know that $\varphi$ will be isomorphism if there is another morphism $\psi: V(E_2) \to V(E_1)$ such that $$\varphi \circ \psi =id_{V(E_2)},~~\psi \circ \varphi=id_{V(E_1)}.$$

So let $\psi:=[f_1,f_2,f_3]$ be another morphism such that $$\varphi \circ \psi=id_{V(E_2)}=[1,1,1],$$ where $f_i, ~i=1,2,3$ are homogeneous polynomials in $\mathbb Q[X,Y,Z]$.

If I am correct, then  the last equation gives $$ f_1=Y/72+Z/2, f_2=Z/2-Y/72, f_3=X/12$$ i.e., $$\psi:=[Y/72+Z/2, Z/2-Y/72, X/12],$$ which exists at all points of $\mathbb P^2(\mathbb Q)$.

Comment: Yes, this is correct (minor nitpick - you want the composition to be $[X:Y:Z]$, not $[1:1:1]$ - the former is the identity on $\Bbb P^2$ while the latter is the constant map to a point). What you're running in to here is that linear endomorphisms of projective space are invertible iff the matrix representing the map is, and to find the inverse it suffices to invert the matrix.

Comment: @KReiser, Thanks a lot. The Jacobian matrix of $\varphi$ is $\begin{pmatrix} 0&0&12 \\ 36 &-36&0 \\ 1&1&0 \end{pmatrix}$, which has inverse $\begin{pmatrix} 0&1/72&1/2 \\ 0 &-1/72&1/2 \\ 1/12&0&0 \end{pmatrix}$ so that $[X~Y~Z]\begin{pmatrix} 0&1/72&1/2 \\ 0 &-1/72&1/2 \\ 1/12&0&0 \end{pmatrix}=[Y/72+Z/2,Z/2-Y/72,X/12]=\varphi^{-1}$.

Comment: @KReiser do you want to post that as an answer?

Comment: It's not just that the inverse of the "Jacobian" is that matrix, $\phi$ itself is multiplication by that matrix. In fact the Jacobian of $\phi$ should be a $2\times 2$ matrix, not $3 \times 3$. Finally, you could clear denominators and say $\psi([X: Y: Z]) = [36Z + Y: 36Z - Y: 6X]$.

Comment: @ronno no, you can if you want.