# To find an isomorphism from a hyperplane in an ambient projective space to another projective space?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, diophantine-equations, arithmetic-dynamics

Consider the hyperplane $$X:=V(a_0x_0+a_1x_1+\cdots+a_Nx_N+a_{N+1}x_{N+1}) \subset \mathbb P^{N+1},$$ where $a_0,a_1, \cdots, a_{N+1} \in \mathbb Q$ are not all zero. Define the height function as follows: $$H(P)=\max \{|x_0|,|x_1|, \cdots, |x_N|\},~P=(x_0, \cdots, x_{N}) \in \mathbb P^N(\mathbb Q).$$

> I need to prove that for each integer $M \geq 1$, $$\#\{P \in X(\mathbb Q): H(P) \leq M \} \leq C(2M+1)^{(N+1)}$$ for some constants $C>0$.

---

At first we recall the following lemma:

**Lemma (Northcott property):** Fix an integer $n \geq 1$, there are at most $(2M+1)^{(n+1)}$ of points in $\mathbb P^n(\mathbb Q)$ of height $M$.

To prove the statement, it is sufficient to show that $$X \cong \mathbb P^N(\mathbb Q).$$
Then by using the above lemma and taking $C=1$, the statement will follow.

So how to construct an isomporphism between the hyperplane $X$ and the projective space $\mathbb P^{N}(\mathbb Q)$, where $X$ lies in the ambient space $\mathbb P^{(N+1)}(\mathbb Q)$.

Let us recall that the notation $[x_0:x_1: \cdots:x_N]$ stands for equivalence class of points in $\mathbb P^N(\mathbb Q)$. Two points $(x_0, \cdots, x_N)$ and $(y_0, \cdots, y_N)$ are equivalent if $$(x_0, \cdots, x_N)=\lambda (y_0, \cdots, y_N)$$ for some non zero element $\lambda \in \mathbb Q$.

So if I define a map $f: X \to \mathbb P^N(\mathbb Q)$ by $$g(x_0, \cdots, x_N,x_{N+1})=(\frac{x_0}{x_{N+1}}: \frac{x_1}{x_{N+1}}, \cdots, \frac{x_N}{x_{N+1}}).$$
This seems injective.

But we need surjectivity as well. Does the above map help ?

Comment: Your guess isn't even a map in general, unfortunately - think about where it would take $[0:\cdots:0:1]$. Hint: can you solve the same problem for vector spaces?

Comment: @KReiser, thanks. $[0:\cdots:0:1]$ will go to $[0:\cdots:0]$, so not injective

Comment: No, it's worse, that's not even a point in protective space - your putative map isn't actually a map. I really do recommend checking out the previous hint.

Comment: @KReiser, aah yes, I am silly. Infact the equivalence relation I defined above with "non-zero multiplier" requires to remove the zero vector. Infact there is no equivalence class of points consisting the zero in any projective space

Comment: @KReiser, But $\mathbb P^N(\mathbb Q)$ is not a vector space, instead set of vector lines in a vector space of dimension $N+1$. So how to think in vector spaces, can you please explain ? However, if we modify the map $f:X \to \mathbb P^N(\mathbb Q)$ by $f(x_0, \cdots, x_{N+1})=[1: \frac{x_1}{x_0}:\frac{x_2}{x_0} \cdots:\frac{x_N}{x_0}]$, then it is a map, dividing by $x_0$. May be we can find its inverse also.  What do you say ?

Comment: You used a linear map in your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4545035/how-to-find-an-isomorphism-between-two-projecive-subvarieties) - why do you resist looking at a linear map now? If you don't engage with the hint I gave, I will not have anything further to say to you on this post. (I might not have anything further to say to you here anyways - it's kind of tiring when I keep giving the same hint which will solve your problem and you keep ignoring it.)

Comment: @KReiser, I am sorry. But if I consider the linear map $f(x_0,\cdots, x_{N+1})=(x_0+\sum_{i=1}^{N+1}x_i,x_1+\sum_{i=2}^{N+1}x_i, \cdots, x_N+x_{N+1})$, then its Jacobian matrix is upper triangular with non-zero diagonals, so invertible. Just we have to check whether it is a map or not, for example I can not see whether its image contains zero vector or not.